# Can someone infect me with virus or spypare on subversion?

Tags: svn

I gave an external person access to my SVN which is on a VPS server.
After he made his first update to SVN, I downloaded the updates to my local computer, and AVG popped with a malware message:

```
 "";"Could be a Trojan horse JS/Exploit, ....\.svn\pristine\8c\8c617a95755954db9119b49ddfe343588e486175.svn-base";"Unresolved";"File or Directory";"4/27/2016, 10:21:46 AM"
```

I don't know this guy enough, he is an outsourcer. Could it be that he by purpose infected me by purpose in order to steal information from my computer or from my server?

My AVG blocked the files on my computer, but how exposed is my server?